# Force the orientation of Admob

Tags: android, orientation, admob

I want to know if there is a possibility to force the orientation of an Admob Banner (4.3.1) for Android. My game force the player to play in landscape, but I would like to put the Ad at the vertical. Like this the Ad will destroy less space on the screen and I can put the ad at a better place to get clicks.

I already saw games like this, but I don't remember which one... Oh, and my Ad is only on a XML file, so if I can use it without JAVA code, it would be excellent.

I found nothing on my research :S

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, AdMob does not support a 50x320 creative.

Comment: Hummmm, so there's no way to flip the banner... Ok, Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0):

You can flip it, but the content will still be in a different orientation. And this should be done probably in the code. I don't exactly know hoe.

[This link might help](http://johnehartzog.com/2009/04/admob-ad-to-landscape-orientation/)